# How to remove minSdkVersion from AndroidManifest.xml but still be able to build with Make?

Tags: gradle, android-manifest, android-source, android.mk

I need to be able to build an application with both Gradle (for development) and with Make (for AOSP). Building the app in Android Studio and with Gradle from the command line complains about this line of code:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="28"/>
```

If I remove it and build with Make, it breaks. I need to be able to have it removed in the AndroidManifest.xml but still be able to build with Make for AOSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with Make, I found this to be helpful: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-building/16UChSc3o7A

I removed that line mentioned in the description from the AndroidManifest.xml file, and then added this to the Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_MIN_SDK_VERSION := 28
```